# Function with optimized parameters does not come close to data using mle2 in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-modeling

So I've been trying to optimize a Michaelis-Menten relationship with a gamma error distribution to model the average of some data that I have collected. However, no matter how I optimize the function, the lowest AIC I get is for parameters that don't even come close to the data. Is there any way I could solve this?

Here's my code:

I first create a maximum likelihood function:

```
MicNLL <- function(a,b){
  #a=150.6727
  #b=319.7007 optim val
  top <- a*x
  bot <- b+x
  Mic <- top/bot
  nll <- -sum(dgamma(y, shape=(Mic^2/var(x)), scale=(var(x)/Mic), log=TRUE))
  return(nll)
}
```

Then I have written the optimization function using the `mle2()` function in the `bbmle` package:

```
MN <- mle2(minuslogl = MicNLL, parameters=list(a~Treatment, b~Treatment), start=list(a=100,b=260), data=list(x=NSug3$VolpulT, y=NSug3$SugarpugT), control=list(maxit=1e4), method="SANN", hessian=T)

MN 
AICMN <- (2*2)-(2*logLik(MN))
AICMN
```

While the eyeballed parameters of a=100 & b=260 would fit nicely with my data, it usually optimizes the parameters to a=242 & b=182, which results

```
Michealis <- function(a, b, x){
  top <- a*x
  bot <- b+x
  Mic <- top/bot
  return(Mic)
}
ggplot(NSug3, aes(x=VolpulT, y=SugarpugT))+
  geom_point(stat="identity", size=0.8)+
  theme_classic()+
  ggtitle("help")+
  ylab("Sugar concentration")+
  xlab("Volume per Extra floral nectary")+
  stat_function(fun= Michealis, args=c(a=100, b=260), colour="Orange", size=0.725)+
  stat_function(fun= Michealis, args=c(a=MN@coef[[1]], b=MN@coef[[2]]), colour="Red", size=0.725)
```

[image: data model]

So long story short, how can I make sure my optimized model actually runs through my data?

Answer (score 1):

With apologies for brain-dumped code below ...

I made a reproducible example similar to yours that seems to give reasonable results.

- are you getting any warnings about failure to converge/"max iterations reached"?
- there seems to be some unused/leftover stuff about Treatment in your code; that's a good idea, but will only work with the formula interface (see below)

Some helper functions:

```
## Gamma parameterized by mean and variance
## m = a*s, v = a*s^2 -> s=v/m; a=m^2/v
rgamma2 <- function(n, m, v) {
    rgamma(n, shape=m^2/v, scale=v/m)
}
dgamma2 <- function(x, m, v, log=FALSE) {
    dgamma(x, shape=m^2/v, scale=v/m, log=log)
}
sgamma2<- function(m, v) {   ## for predict()
    list(title="Gamma", mean=m, sd=sqrt(v))
}
mm <- function(x, a=100, b=260) {
    a*x/(b+x)
}
```

Simulate data:

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rlnorm(100,meanlog=4,sdlog=1)
dd <- data.frame(x,y=rgamma2(100,m=mm(x), v= 100))
```

Fit (using formula interface):

```
library(bbmle)
m1 <-mle2(y~dgamma2(m=mm(x,a,b),v=exp(logv)),
     start=list(a=50,b=200,logv=0),
     data=dd,
     control=list(maxit=1000))
```

Plot results:

```
plot(y~x,data=dd)
lines(sort(dd$x),mm(sort(dd$x)),col=2)     ## true
lines(sort(dd$x),sort(predict(m1)),col=3)  ## predicted
```

Comment: I didn't get any errors, but your code seemed to fix my problem! Thank you so much!  While it does work, I was wondering why exactly does optimizing the log fix the problem?  Is it because that allows for more leeway in the process or is it due to something else? And does this extra parameter also affect the AIC, or should it not be accounted for in the AIC calculation?

Comment: Furthermore, if I want then want to use this model to compare different treatments with my data, do I need to readd the parameters = list(a~treatment) or can I leave that out?

Comment: you need to put it back in

Comment: Right, thank you very much, after some fiddling it worked! :)